# greengoplatform and cofounderspecials malware

Tags: web, redirect, ads, malware

I want to clean my website from malware the redirect every page to an ad page titeld "greengoplatform" or "cofounderspecial", so i started cleaning every file removes some imposter codes yet still there is the same problem.
When i go to the website throught mozilla firefox i can see the that there is a TLS HANDSHAKE to greengoplatform.com .
I have a wordpress website, i used many plugins but none of them was usefull.
i don't know where could be the main malware code .

Comment: I am having the same problem! have you fixed it?

Comment: kind of fixed it by  checking the php pages and turning every includ code to a comment , to figure out the infected page , so when i found the page i started to remove the "<script >" code one by one  until i found the js script that leaded me to the js file infected and i removed it .